# Allocating memory for void star

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I've a method which goes like the following -

```
int rtable_add(RESIZABLE_TABLE * table, char * name, void * value) {
     char *foo = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);
     foo = name;
     //Need to do the same for value
     table->array[table->currentElements].name = strdup(foo);
     table->array[table->currentElements].value = value;
     table->currentElements++;
}
```

I am adding elements passed to this method to a table. The parameter value is void type and can basically be a char* or a long. I want to add this value to my table but with the current way I am doing it, it's adding values that don't make sense. I figure that I need to allocate memory before I do that for "value" but not sure how would I malloc for a void in my situation?

EDIT : I've these methods that are making a call to rtable_add to add elements to the table -

```
int rtable_add_str(RESIZABLE_TABLE * table, char * name, char * str_value)
{
   return rtable_add(table, name, (void *) strdup(str_value));
}

int rtable_add_int(RESIZABLE_TABLE * table, char * name, long int_value)
{
    return rtable_add(table, name, (void *) int_value );
}
```

Comment: You have not given us enough information to diagnose your problem. However, if you ever intend on dereferenceing `value` then you need to store its type somewhere.  BTW, you are immediately leaking the memory allocated to `foo`.

Comment: Per your edit, you're casting a `long` to a pointer to `void`, which is wrong.  The *value* of `int_value` is being interpreted as an address. You should compile with warnings enabled.  You can't pass the address of `int_value` either because it is a local copy. A pointer to `long` would need to be passed to your function, though you now have to think about who owns that memory.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1, don't write it explicitly. Don't cast a pointer value to `void*`, it will be implicitly converted. Cannot say whether casting the `long` to `void*` is allowed or not, as it depends on your implementation (and possibly the value-range actually converted), though probably innocuous. Might be a logic-error though, who knows...